# about the first file when iterate a series files in R

Tags: r

I want to `rbind` a series of tables each read from a single file. If I use loop/iteration to append one by one,How to set the first table used to append?

```
fs=list.files('D:/',full.names=T)
sum=?       #how to initialized the sum
for (f in fs){  
  temp <- read.table(f,header=F,sep=' ',skip=1,row.names=NULL)
  sum <- rbind(sum,temp)  
}
```

For general case, How to set the "sum" when do iteration in R?

Comment: (1) I recommend against naming it `sum`, the name of a common function in R; (2) this is a very inefficient way of combining many tables; (3) *"tables ... from a single file"* is a bit vague, `read.table` reads one table from a file, reading multiple is certainly feasible but not with what little you've provided. If `fs` is a vector of filenames, then `do.call(rbind, lapply(fs, read.table, header=F, sep=' ', skip=1, row.names=NULL))` might suffice.

Comment: `fs` are files .`do.call` is very usefull.but how to add all single file into a vector? Maybe could not without a  loop .

Comment: A vector is 1d, a table is 2d, what am I missing? My suggested method needs and uses no loops, I don't understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a initialition method,as follows:

```
for (f in fs){
  df <- read.table(f,header=F,sep=' ',skip=1,row.names=NULL)
  if (!exists('all_data')){
    all_data <- df
  }
   if (exists('all_data')){
    all_data <- rbind(all_data,df)
  }
}
```